# php required_once Fatal error base_dir bug

Tags: php, require-once, open-basedir

### Yay all !

I've got a weird error :

> Warning: require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/lib/php/api/api.conf.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/admin.eatsalad.fr/subdomains/dev:/usr/lib/php/:/tmp:/var/www/html/dnpanel/) in /var/www/vhosts/admin.eatsalad.fr/subdomains/dev/system/include_libs.php on line 3

Well, i try to get `/usr/lib/php/api/api.conf.php` which is obviously in `/usr/lib/php/`

The file exist, do I need to use chmod maybe ?
I search around here, but except bug about "file as folder open_basedir bug" like, I get nothing.

Thanks for helpers =) !

---

### Solution

Ok, here goes the solution, with the dnpanel all "sub" website are in a jail
So, even in php i wrote down /usr/lib/php, in reality, files are in /httpjail/usr/lib/php.

And, obviously, my libs were in /usr/lib/php which is not the good real path.

Thanks everyone for everything anyway ;)

Comment: Have you read the error fully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Ok, here goes the solution, with the dnpanel all "sub" website are in a jail
So, even in php i wrote down /usr/lib/php, in reality, files are in /httpjail/usr/lib/php.

And, obviously, my libs were in /usr/lib/php which is not the good real path.

Thanks everyone for everything anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12628444/446594) adding a slash to a directory listed in the setting will prevent requiring files inside subdirectories of that directory.

If u look at your setting its `/var/www/vhosts/admin.eatsalad.fr/subdomains/dev:/usr/lib/php/:/tmp:/var/www/html/dnpanel/`, meaning u can't require files from a subdirectory inside /user/lib/php